# Defining the click event for a Login control integrated button

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Gooday. I have a **login** control, **with an integrated user textbox and login button**. I did this little test to see how it works, and surprisingly, after doing this:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            TextBox userTextBox = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
            userTextBox.Text = "You pressed the button";
}
```

the userTextBox doesn't change to "You pressed the button". Why?
Thanks. Anna

**EDIT: Sure, here is the markup (most of it is generated automatically by the system when adding the Login control); you will notice a button  LoginButton integrated in the Login:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:Panel ID="searchPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="login1$LoginButton">
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
    FailureText="Logarea a esuat. Reincercati!" LoginButtonText="Logati-va!" 
    PasswordLabelText="Parola:" 
    PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Trebuie sa introduceti parola." 
    RememberMeText="Tine-ma minte!" TitleText="Logare" 
    UserNameLabelText="Nume de utilizator:" 
    UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Trebuie sa introduceti numele de utilizator.">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
                style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    Logare</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Nume 
                                    de utilizator:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                .........
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" 
                                        Text="Logati-va!" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

The code-behind goes liek this:

```
namespace Cinemax
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                        //userTextBox.Focus(); // this sets the focus on the username textbox when the page loads
            this.Title = CinemaxConfiguration.SiteName + ": Login";


        }

        protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox userTextBox = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
            TextBox userPassword = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");

            //Button loginBtn = (Button)Login1.FindControl("LoginButton");
            userTextBox.Text = "You pressed me";

            if (User1.ConnAttempt(userTextBox.Text, userPassword.Text) == 1)
            {
                Session["User"] = userTextBox.Text;
                Response.Redirect("Catalog.aspx");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the markup?

Comment: Are you using a <asp:Login control?

Comment: Yes, I am using a <asp:Login> control. I edited my question to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the TestBox an ASP server control, and is runat=Server?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but do you ever actually bind it back to the control.

You are creating a new textbox that is initialised from your login control.

You then set the text of that textbox, but i dont think thta will bind it back to the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the application, does it show that the text gets set?

also, do you have something in the Page_Load method that sets the text box value? you should put things in a

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
userTextBox.Text = ""
}
```

statement

Comment: Thanks kolin, no I don't set the userTextBox text from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

check if your control is runat=server and you have binded the control to the event

```
    this.LoginButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.LoginButton_Click);
```

Comment: Thanks Tanuj, I hadn't done that. I included it now in Page_Load, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: not in the page_load, you need to include it in the designer.cs file

Comment: right click on the button in the design view and go to its properties. In the events tag, check if the LoginButton_Click method is called in the click event.

Comment: Thanks Tanuj! I just did that, and indeed in the event list, the event method didn't show up. So I manually generated its signature and filled the body as previously said, but still its purpose isn't met (to show some text on the label after click).

Comment: on the label or on the TextBox? Is the page posted back on the click event?

Answer (score 0):

In your login control check if you are setting some value of `userTextBox` in `Page_Load` or any other event, as it appears that its value is being set from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind it to the Form. . .